# Error with git pull and git push

Tags: windows, git, github

I have a problem when i try to send file to github with git push. The same error occur with git pull.

This is the error:

```
 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/"something"/': error:1407742E
:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

But i updated my git and my windows 8.1. But the error persist.

Somebody know how to solve this problem ?

**Edited**

I installed the openssl library for windows in my computer becouse in lib of git have a folder openssl. But this not solve. I swap the folders but not solve too.

How to update this library in git ?

Comment: For https (authenticated web server via SSL) access, Git relies on third-party SSL libraries. The error comes from the third-party code (so you must upgrade that, not Git itself). Consider using ssh, which also relies on third-party code: the secure shell code is better-isolated and easier to upgrade if needed.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: I should add, I don't use Windows and do not know how any of the Windows updates work. On Linux there are issues where SSL libraries are versioned and upgrading won't necessarily help because the code will still use the wrong (old) library.